# Mac VBA code to select a form option button

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I can writing VBA in Mac os. The below code in excel (windows) check an option button.

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Otion button 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value=true

This code does not work in Mac excel.

Can anyone help to get the code for Mac excel to do this function.
Thank  you,

Comment: It looks like when I insert an Option button it is named "OptionButton1". You might have extra spaces and be missing a "p" :)

Comment: My real option button name is not "OptionButton1" .  It is not necessary that the name in quotes should be  "OptionButton1" . we can add custom name that  the same name should match in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted doesn't work in the Windows environment either. It results in an error: "Runtime error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

After exploring the locals window, I found that the correct way to access this value is through a double .object ... So your code would be:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Otion button 1").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = True
```